# OnkeyUp event is missed sometimes

Tags: javascript, websocket, dom-events, onkeydown, onkeyup

I have an HTML5 web application which works as a KVM screen using WebSockets. Basically a virtual monitor for my remote machine. The problem I see is when I start typing fast (or continuously) one of the characters get printed multiple times.

The code is such that, the key pressed/released is conveyed to the remote system as a USB HID protocol. So as per [USB-HID Protocol](https://docs.mbed.com/docs/ble-hid/en/latest/api/md_doc_HID.html#keyboard),

> When the OS receives a "press key" report, it writes the letter or
> uses it as a command as explained above. It will keep performing the
> same action, again and again, until it receives a "release key"
> report.
> When you press the letter 'a' on a USB keyboard, the following report
> will be sent over the USB interrupt pipe:
>
> 'a' report:     [0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0] This '4' value is the Keycode
> for the letter 'a', as described in USB HID Usage Tables (Section 10:
> Keyboard/Keypad Page). That document defines the report formats for
> all standardized HIDs.
>
> After releasing the key, the following report will be sent:
>
> null report:    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0] '4' is replaced with '0'; an
> array of zeros means nothing is being pressed.

Accordingly, the HTML5 web application sends a packet for key-press & a separate packet for key-release. It makes use of `onKeyDown()` to send key-press event & `onKeyUp()` to send key-release event.

At times, the `onKeyUp()` event is not received, thereby not allowing the application to send a key-release event & therefore the pressed character continues to print.

So the issue is the missing `onKeyUp()` event. How can I ensure this does not happen? What could be the reasons for it? I am running this on Chrome on Win 7.
Could there be an alternate solution to achieve the above task?

Comment: As far as I know there isn't a clear answer, since the keyboard doesn't actually register that as a 'keyup' or whatever situation it didn't register. If you press the key again it should fix it though.

Comment: @JaredBledsoe yes it does fix the issue if I press the key again, the real issue is at times when some configurations/installations are to be done & on those screens if the "Enter" key gets repeated it does not allow the user to set their configurations. The issue gets severe in those scenarios.